# Big response from a PHP API gets corrupted

Tags: http, curl, nginx, php

I have a server running on Nginx + PHP-FPM. There is a PHP script on it, which gets an HTTP request and responds on it with a large set of data (let it be 100K records), taken from DB (MongoDB).

Response is formed record by record, each record followed by newline and being echo'ed to the client and flushed immediately.

The client here is another server on similar platform. HTTP request is made by CURL with CURLOPT_FILE set so we don't try and store all the data in memory.

Some lines in the file, which contains a response, get corrupted (they contain lots of NUL bytes followed by normally looking data). This happens for seamingly random response lines, about once for 1K response lines.

I'd appreciate if somebody hinted me at least what COULD be wrong here so I could find a solution.

This code sends a response:

```
    set_time_limit(self::TIME_LIMIT);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    //clear the buffers
    if (ob_get_level())
    {
        while (@ob_end_flush());
    }
    findAndProcessRecord($this->request, function(RecordClass $record) {
        echo $this->packRecord($record) . "\n";
        flush();
    });
```

`packRecord()` method basically encrypts data and then `base64_encode()`s it

This code makes a request by CURL:

```
            $url = $project->apiUrl . '?' . http_build_query($requestParams);
            $responseFile = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

            ini_set('memory_limit', self::MEM_LIMIT . 'M');
            set_time_limit(self::TIME_LIMIT);
            $curlResource = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt_array(
                $curlResource,
                [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => self::CURL_TIMEOUT,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => false,
                    CURLOPT_FILE => $responseFile,
                    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                ]
            );
            curl_exec($curlResource);
```

In `$responseFile` we have a handle for an opened file, which has the response inside. Then this handle is used to construct an iterator and traverse the response lines.

Comment: I think I'm running against the same issue, narrowed it down to PHP5-FPM wondering if you found a solution?

Comment: @AhmadNassri, no, I still don't have a clue about the cause of this thing.